# Make Excel Slicers Jump to values selected by other slicers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I've got a set of 3 slicers on a pivot table linked to a SSAS cube.  The slicers are Year, Month and Date.  The date slicer is ridiculously large, displaying my entire date dimension to the year 2100.

I'd like to have the user Select the Year and have the Month Slicer 'jump' to January of that year.  Byy def

The Date slicer would also jump to the Jan 1 Date.  When a Month slicer value is selected, the Date slicer would also jump to the proper month.

Does anyone have some sample code to do something similar?  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like a record macro could go a long ways to answering this questino

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I recorded a macro and tried it out, but the actual focus of the slicer doesn't move to show the selected values.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll have to create two text selection boxes and have them trigger filtering of the pivot table as the slicers don't seem to be meant for large amounts of data.